# Handle close event of the window in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, nswindowcontroller, nsviewcontroller

How to handle close event of the window using swift, for example, to ask "Are you sure you want to close the form?"

[image]

The form will be closed in the case "yes" and not closed in the case "no". Showing message box is not a problem for me.

viewWillDisappear() works for minimizing also, but I need only close event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Like said above, you should make the `ViewController` an `NSWindowDelegate`, but you should handle `windowWillClose`, not `windowShouldClose`. `windowShouldClose` is to determine if the window is able to close or not, not an event that the window is actually closing.

I also found that you need to set up the `delegate` in `viewDidAppear`, not `viewDidLoad`. For me `self.view.window` wasn't defined yet in `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    self.view.window?.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: what does self.view.window?.delegate = self do exactly plz?

Comment: Sets the ViewController to be a delegate for the Window that the ViewController represents. It allows the ViewController that is conforming to the NSWindowDelegate protocol to actually function as a delegate.

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same query too, solved it using the method explained in detail here: [Quit Cocoa App when Window Close using XCode Swift 3](https://nabtron.com/quit-cocoa-app-window-close/)

It needs three steps:

1. Conform toNSWindowDelegate in your ViewController class
2. Override viewDidAppear method
3. Add windowShouldClose method

The added code should look like this:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {
    // ... rest of the code goes here
    override func viewDidAppear() {
        self.view.window?.delegate = self
    }
    func windowShouldClose(_ sender: Any) {
        NSApplication.shared().terminate(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: windowShouldClose is a delegate method that returns a boolean value to determine if the window should be allowed to close or not. You should be using windowWillClose. You also don't need to manually terminate the application in code. There is an NSApplicationDelegate method you can put in your AppDelegate to have the app close when all windows are closed.  func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

Answer (score 4):

Just add this function to AppDelegate ...

```
func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed (_ theApplication: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `NSWindowDelegate` protocol in your ViewController class. (See the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowShouldClose:))

To make your class conform to the protocol:

```
class ViewController: NSObject, NSWindowDelegate
```

To detect when the window's close button has been clicked, use `windowShouldClose:`

From the doc:

> Tells the delegate that the user has attempted to close a window [...]

In this method, you can use [NSAlert](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAlert/setIcon:) to prompt the user on whether or not they really want to close the window.

**EDIT** (in response to @Mr Beardsley's comment)

To make your ViewController the delegate, use:

```
window.delegate = self
```

Where `self` is the ViewController and `window` is the window you're using. You can put this in `viewDidLoad:`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I set "class ViewController: NSObject, NSWindowDelegate" and realized function windowShouldClose. But it doesn't work. I believe I should set the delegate property for the window but I don't know how.

Comment: To set the delegate from your View Controller just do something like: "window.delegate = self"   In viewDidLoad (as long as you are on 10.10 or later). You will need a reference or IBOutlet to the window in question as well.