# Trying to know when a window closes in a macOS Document based application

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm trying to know when a window closes, I implemented this code:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let window: NSWindow? = view.window
        window?.delegate = self
    }

    func windowWillClose(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        print("windowWillClose")
    }

}
```

Unfortunately nothing happens, what could I made wrong?

Documents: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419400-willclosenotification

PS
I already read this question without to find a solution: [Handle close event of the window in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215860/handle-close-event-of-the-window-in-swift)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem there is that the window property will always return nil inside viewDidLoadMethod.  You need to set the delegate inside viewWillAppear method:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {
    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        view.window?.delegate = self
    }
    func windowWillClose(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        print("windowWillClose")
    }
}
```