# Window will not close even if self.view.window?.close() is used

Tags: swift, macos

So I am trying to make a ***macOS*** window close after a selected period of time. I read online that I could use `self.view.window?.close` to make it disappear. So far, that is not working.

Do any of you have any tips?

Also, I want it to open another window after the 1st one closes. So I don't want it to quit the app entirely.

EDIT: I found out by using `print(self.view.window`) was set to `nil`. What does that mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that `self.view.window` isn't `nil`?

Comment: @rmaddy Let me check that :)

Comment: @rmaddy It IS nil! How do I go fix that?

Answer (score 0):

this is redundant code but sometimes I have managed to solve this issue like this:

```
// Window reference
var window: NSWindow?  

// After window is displayed, get the handle to it
window = self.view.window!

// To dismiss it try
window?.performClose(nil) // nil or empty value
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your code failed on 'window = self.view.window!' with: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: @TheUbuntuMaster you just need to move your code from viewDidLoad to `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods.

Comment: @LeoDabus How do you do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44685445/trying-to-know-when-a-window-closes-in-a-macos-document-based-application